# Importing bitbucket team repo into careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm running a public project on bitbucket. But its repository is owned by my team, not by me directly. If I try to import this project into my carrers profile using `bitbucket` link - I can't see the repository in the list for. That looks correct since I don't own this repo.

If I try to paste direct link to bitbucket project - I get *use bitbucket import* error message.

Question: is there any way to import this kind of repository?

Comment: I would really like this to be possible as well, I have several long running projects which I can't display from BitBucket because they are owned by the team not by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to import a team-owned bitbucket repository to your careers profile:

1. Go to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) and log in *with your team account* (not with your personal account).
2. Make sure the repositories you're contributing to aren't private: under *settings*, "This is a private repository" needs to be un-checked.
3. Go to your [careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit), click on "add or update: bitbucket"
4. Select projects to import
5. Make sure to go back to teambucket and log out your team account.

Comment: There is no team account in that team :)
At least I didn't create account, didn't set password etc. But it is an idea, thanks, I'll try this week.

Comment: Check with the rest of the team - someone should own the team account: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+an+individual+or+team+account

Comment: I just logged in with the Team Account to receive: After February 18, 2014, you'll need to log in using an individual user account with administrator access to manage this team. - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/bII7Gg How would you do it then?